# Are database read_timeout and write_timeout unique to ActiveRecord or native to mysql?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, timeout

ActiveRecord allows you to configure database read_timeout and write_timeout values, for example:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydb
  pool: 5
  username: myuser
  password: mypass
  host: myhost
  write_timeout: 2
  read_timeout: 10
```

Are read_timeout and write_timeout unique to ActiveRecord, or are those part of the mysql spec? I know that mysql has the concept of [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout), but I don't believe that is the same as query timeouts.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have never used mysql gem. But I think you can see mysql variables which are used by ActiveRecord like this.

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('show variables like "%timeout%"').to_a
=> [["connect_timeout", "10"],
 ["delayed_insert_timeout", "300"],
 ["innodb_flush_log_at_timeout", "1"],
 ["innodb_lock_wait_timeout", "50"],
 ["innodb_rollback_on_timeout", "OFF"],
 ["interactive_timeout", "28800"],
 ["lock_wait_timeout", "31536000"],
 ["net_read_timeout", "30"],
 ["net_write_timeout", "60"],
 ["rpl_stop_slave_timeout", "31536000"],
 ["slave_net_timeout", "3600"],
 ["wait_timeout", "2147483"]]
```